# Android splash screen image sizes

Tags: android, xamarin.android

does anybody know sizes for Android splash screen images that'll work with 20:9 screen ratios as well as tablets? I've got full size images so 9patch won't work me. Thanks

Comment: General advice for things like a splash screen is to pick something where if the edges are cut off it still looks good, so you don't have to worry about slightly different aspect ratios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to manage this is using Vector Drawables that are made out of SVG Images(not to use in case of pictures with sharp details),

- Ask your designer to provide you with an `SVG` image for your splash screen.
- Use [svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) converter to convert the image into a `VectorDrawable`.
- Use this vector drawable as image source as follows:

  ```
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_vector" //xml
  _yourImageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.your_vector); // C#
  ```
- Also, Note that you need to use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of your normal `ImageView` for this to work.
- And in the OnCreate of your `MainApplication` class that inherits the Application class add the following line of code.

  ```
  AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled=(true);
  ```

And in case you want to do it the old fashioned way I would suggest you use `1687x3653` for `20:9`

Comment: Depends on what type of image he has.  SVG does really well for things like icons.  Its an incredibly poor format for things like photos.\

Comment: Yes true that is the reason i mentioned at the start to use use only if its a basic image @GabeSechan